# How can I name a voice memo in iTunes

Tags: itunes, voice-memo

How can I add a name or title to the voice memos that sync from my iPhone to iTunes on my Mac? All I get in the playlist is the date and duration of the memo - right click, left click, nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

You can rename your voice recording using the "Get Info" window, which you can invoke by:

- Choosing **File > Get Info**
- Or, right-clicking and choosing "Get Info"
- Or, pressing <kbd>⌘ I</kbd>

From there, click on the "Info" tab, and you can enter something else in the "Name" field:

[image]

The same procedure works on all other files in iTunes as well, like music and movies.